# how to insert into multiple record in laravel controller

Tags: php, controller, laravel-5

i have basic like this

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $input = Input::all();


    $schedule = new Schedule;
    $student->name = $input['name'];
    $student->for_date = $input['for_date'];
    $student->save();
    return view('students.index');
}
```

My plan is ' what if I want to include the same students and for_date for today and the next day'

may be like this,..

```
-------------------
|name | for_date  |
-------------------
|eka  | 2016-09-04|
|eka  | 2016-09-05|
|eka  | 2016-09-06|
|eka  | 2016-09-07|
```

anyone have any suggestions? please, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

frontend post array datas, then just use foreach.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $inputArrays = Input::all();
    $schedule = new Schedule;
    foreach ($inputArrays as $array) {
        $student->name = $name;
        $student->for_date = $date;
        $student->save();
    }
    return view('students.index');
}
```

Comment: if at the front end just put 1 data only, but of the controller will make the data array, whether it possibly be?

btw, thanks

Comment: @yes, you can serialize datas from frontend then unserialize it at backend.or just use join('|') from frontend then explode('|', datas) from backend

Comment: @ekaputra, if this is useful for you , please take my answer , then both of us can get reputations